# Kubuntu 19.10 Hard Freezes at random times!

Tags: kubuntu

Okay this is becoming a major problem. My PC running Kubuntu 19.10 randomly freezes sometimes. I have no idea when or how so I can't reproduce it. There is literally nothing I can do to make it work except hard-reboot it from the power button. I can't switch TTY, I can't SSH, nothing.
I tried SSHing to try and see if dmesg gives me an error message I can post here but that didn't work. Any ideas?
The PC takes no input from any device either. Mouse and keyboard completely stop working.

Here's my hardware-

Ryzen 5 1600

Nvidia GTX 1660Ti (Zotac)

Corsair Vengeance 3000MHz 16 Gigs (8x2)

This happened in Manjaro too. More often, in fact. In Ubuntu it doesn't happen as often but when it does, it's incredibly annoying. Imagine I'm working on something really important and I have to suddenly hard reboot and lose all my work...

The only guess I have is this- (and it's a real shot in the dark)

The screen never freezes when I have logs on the screen. (I have been keeping `dmesg -wH`, `tty-clock` and `htop` open in `tmux` for a few days so if it freezes, I can get some info).
It usually freezes when there's no significant movement on the screen for a few minutes/seconds. So I'm guessing it's SOMEHOW related to GPU drivers. I have absolutely no idea if that's right, though. The screen obviously still has SOME movement because the time in the clock in my panel is obviously changing.

Comment: A fast google search of the CPU shows quite a few people with same problem on different Linux and I think Windows systems.  Some are mark as solved, but not necessary with your setup.  Try search with ubuntu Ryzen 5 1600 hard freeze and see if any help.

Comment: Try to install older version of kernel